# django/wagtail model - if ForeignKey wagtailimages.Image field is saved blank, then save default

Tags: django, wagtail

I am saving a model for a `BlogPage(Page)` and want to allow author to input image, but if they choose not to, automatically save a specific image.

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from core.models import Page
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey, ParentalManyToManyField
from modelcluster.tags import ClusterTaggableManager
from wagtail.wagtailimages.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel


class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField('Post Date')
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
    feed_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
```

Would the best way to set a `ForeignKey` on `save()` be by:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.feed_image = None:
        self.feed_image = something?
    super(BlogPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

if so, what is the expected input of `something?` an image url?

Or is it cleaner to set a default on the `ForeignKey`, like:

```
feed_image = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    default=something?
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+'
)
```

if so, what would is the expected format of that `something?`?

I know this logic can be done in the template, but it interferes and if possible, I'd like it to be done in the model.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply save `None` on your `feed_image` then create a `get` method that will return your default picture, like that :

```
if self.feed_image:
   return self.feed_image
return something?
```

Answer (score 1):

The something should be a wagtailimages.Image object.

```
self.feed_image = Image.objects.first()
```

But because the feed_image is a ForeignKey field, only an id is stored in the database. So this will work as well (assuming there is a object with that id):

```
self.feed_image_id = 1
```

Finally, I'd like to point out that you are mixing code and content! That is always a bad idea. What if someone deletes your default image? It is better to drop the custom save method, leave the image field empty and use a file from your static folder. Do something like this in the template:

```
{% if object.feed_image %}
   // Your image tag here.
{% else %}
   <img src={% static 'images/default.jpg' %}>
{% endif %}
```